# Angular + minification not working in production and impossible to test

Tags: angularjs

I already know about the dependency injection method and all my controllers, services and directives are built with the following format:

```
App.controller('name', ['myDependency', function (myDependency) { ... }]);
```

Even if I did it running the application in development mode (**not minimized**) it works fine, no issues, no problems, smooth.
Once I try to run it in production mode (**minimized**), it doesn't work anymore.

This is the error in console:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: iProvider <- i
```

Clicking on the link offered by Angular the information are the same I already know, **useless**.

My application is big in terms of controllers, services, etc... but it is built on a single module so I'm pretty sure to have injected all the necessary files.

What I'm using are many vendor dependencies like: `ngRoute`, `ngAnimate`, `ngStorage`, `ngCookies`, etc...

I don't understand why Angular do not provide something more robust and efficient to debug your application to see and fix issues, obviously from a minimized and compressed javascript file is impossible to find the error / bug... so how can I solve it?

I already double, triple checked my own files and all of them contains correctly their dependencies but Angular say there is something wrong, how can I understand from those 10 ridiculous lines in the console log where is the error?

**EDIT**:

Adding `ng-strict-di='true'` and running it in development mode it fire this error, and it doesn't seem to be related at my code... or am I wrong?

```
Error: [$injector:strictdi] function($scope, $element) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/strictdi?p0=function(%24scope%2C%20%24element)
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
    at Function.annotate [as $$annotate] (angular.js:3474)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4181)
    at $get.extend.instance (angular.js:8493)
    at angular.js:7739
    at forEach (angular.js:331)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7738)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7117)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:6996)
    at newCompile (hint.js:2041)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11655$get @ angular.js:8596(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16302completeOutstandingRequest @ angular.js:4924(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5312
```

Comment: If you have `resolve` & inline `controller` function then do check them too

Comment: temporarily use non minified version of angular.js to see the helpful error message.

Comment: all my vendor files are not minized, I use to minimize them just for production.

Comment: Don't minify angular.js by yourself. Use the minified version provided by Angular directly. They took great care to make sure it's both compact, and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `ng-strict-di="true"` attribute to the element where you already apply the `ng-app` directive, and run the app in development mode (i.e. with the non-minified code).

Angular will then throw a meaningful exception explaining where you forgot to use the array notation for your injections.

Note that your code would be much more readable, and you would have much less risk of doing that mistake if you let [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) transform the code for you.

Comment: I will test it now, didn't know about that. Thanks

Comment: I just edited my Question with the error fired by adding it.

Comment: Well, thanks to the `ng-annotate` it added a few more dependencies in a vendor directive and solved my problem. Thanks.